# Which book or source has mentioned Ginny Weasley's name as "Ginevra Weasley"?

Tags: harry-potter

I have encountered "Ginevra Weasley" a number of times in jokes and I recently saw the full name of Ginny on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginny_Weasley):

> **Ginevra Molly "Ginny" Weasley** is a fictional character in J. K. Rowling's Harry Potter series.

Wikipedia doesn't have a citation for this name. Is this correct name? If yes, what's the source?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pottermore has her full name listed on her [character page](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/ginny-weasley)

[image]

That Ginny is short for Ginevra was confirmed in canon in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*.

> ‘Yes, my tiara sets off the whole thing nicely,’ said Auntie Muriel in
> a rather carrying whisper. **‘But I must say, Ginevra’s dress is far too
> low-cut.’
>
> Ginny glanced round, grinning, winked at Harry, then quickly
> faced the front again.** Harry’s mind wandered a long way from the
> marquee, back to afternoons spent alone with Ginny in lonely parts of
> the school grounds. They seemed so long ago; they had always seemed
> too good to be true, as though he had been stealing shining hours from
> a normal person’s life, a person without a lightning-shaped scar on
> his forehead …

---

Her full first name was originally confirmed in May, 2004 on [JKR's old flash-based website](https://web.archive.org/web/20060316221001/https://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=7);

> *Arthur Weasley was one of three brothers. **Ginny (full name Ginevra, not Virginia)**, is the first girl to be born into the Weasley clan for several generations.*

And her middle name was confirmed (by JKR) in March, 2004

> **Kylie:** *Thanks for writing such wonderful books, Ms Rowling :). Just one question: What are Ron, Hermione and Ginny's middle names? Thank you :)*
>
> **JK Rowling:** *My pleasure:) Middle names: **Ginny is Molly, of course**, Hermione 'Jane' and Ron, poor boy, is Bilius.*
>
> <sub><sup>[JK Rowling's World Book Day Chat, March 4, 2004](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2004/0304-wbd.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: Pottermore lists Hermione's middle name as Jean.

Comment: @user931 Canon also gives Hermione's middle name as 'Jean' (scene with Dumbledore's will). Seems like another case of Rowling contradicting one of her interviews in the actual books. She said Grindelwald was dead once before Deathly Hallows came out in which he was alive for a bit of it, didn't she

Comment: According to the wiki she changed it so that she could have Umbridge have the middle name Jane without Hermione having the same middle name

Comment: Ginevra is also mentioned a few pages earlier: *"... and your hair’s much too long, Ronald, for a 
moment I thought you were Ginevra.*

Comment: @Alex - Indeed, but this quote has Ginny mentioned by her (normal) name right underneath :-)

Comment: @user931 might just be the transcript.

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

In the very last book, Ginny is called Ginevra for the only time in the series, by her Auntie Muriel. Her real first name isn't mentioned at all throughout the rest of the Harry Potter books.